# UK business visa not used yet. Is there a 3-month or void clause?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, business-travel

My UK business visa was obtained in October 2016 (for 2 years). I have to travel to the UK from July 28 to Aug 17, 2018 (within the 2-year period) on business (meetings, conference etc).

I am concerned that since I have not yet used my visa, the visa might be void (if memory serves, there used to be a 3-month or void). Is this a possibility? Is there anyway for me to check if the visa is in fact valid?

Comment: Where did you get the information about a "3 month or void" rule?  I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @phoog is there such a restriction for any other kind of entry to the UK? Maybe a misunderstanding started from that.

Comment: @user16259 There may be, but I am unaware of it.  In fact I do not know of such a restriction for any kind of visa anywhere.

Comment: @user1820548, is there any time restriction mentioned on the visa itself?